# Constrained N-Rook Number of Solutions

Tags: algorithm, permutation, n-queens

The purpose of this post is mainly for keywords for related researches.

**Unconstrained N-Rook Problem**

Count all possible arrangements of N rooks on an N by M (N<=M) chessboard so that no rooks are attacking each other.

The solution is trivial: C(M,N)N!

**Constrained N-Rook Problem**

You cannot put a rook at certain places of the chessboard.

For example, if the chessboard is presented as a 0-1 matrix, where 0 are the places you cannot put a rook at. So the solution for the matrix

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
0 1 1
```

is 4:

```
R . . | R . . | . R . | . . R 
. R . | . . R | R . . | R . .
. . R | . R . | . . R | . R .
```

**Related Problem**

A backtracking algorithm can be easily modified from [N-Queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) problem. However, now I want to solve a problem for around N=28. This solution is too huge to count 1 by 1, even [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Counting_solutions) said

> The 27×27 board is the highest-order board that has been completely enumerated.

**Chances to Speed Up**

There are a few chances I thought of so far to speed up the algorithm.

=====Factorial for Unconstrained Submatrix=====

This is a Divide and Conquer method. e.g. The matrix above

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
0 1 1
```

can be divided as

```
  A       B
1 1 1 | 0 1 1
1 1 1 |
```

and the solution is equal to sol(A)*sol(B), where sol(A)=2! which can be calculated at once (factorial is much faster than backtracking).

=============Rearrangement=============

Sometimes rearrangement can help to divide the subproblem. e.g. The matrix

```
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

is equivalent to

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
0 1 1
```

**Question**

1. What is the keyword for this kind of problem?
2. Are there any efficient developed technique for this kind of problem?

Comment: Related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial

Comment: Also http://people.rit.edu/hxssma/Ben-thesis.pdf

Comment: I may be wrong but try searching restricted permutations as well.

Comment: Yes thank you. I think restricted permutations and rook polynomials are a very good starting point for me.

Comment: Related: [Algorithm for Finding the Coefficients of Rook Polynomials](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwijmJHt2vXfAhXYdXAKHV69B_0QFjAAegQIBxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fthaijmath.in.cmu.ac.th%2Findex.php%2Fthaijmath%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F329%2F321&usg=AOvVaw2nh9KrliY1fufjmkwP7lpT)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **rook polynomial**, **rook coefficient**, **restricted permutations** and **permanent** are the keywords.

From Theorem 3.1 of [Algorithm for Finding the Coefficients of Rook Polynomials](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwijmJHt2vXfAhXYdXAKHV69B_0QFjAAegQIBxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fthaijmath.in.cmu.ac.th%2Findex.php%2Fthaijmath%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F329%2F321&usg=AOvVaw2nh9KrliY1fufjmkwP7lpT)

> The number of arrangements of n objects with restriction board B is equal to [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)) of B.

Here B is what we defined in the question, a 0-1 matrix where 1 is ok, 0 is restricted for a rook. 
So now we need to efficiently calculate the permanent of a matrix.

Fortunately, from this [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97123/82702), Ton Hospel uses [Glynn formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent#Balasubramanian%E2%80%93Bax%E2%80%93Franklin%E2%80%93Glynn_formula) with a [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) and [Ryser formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent#Ryser_formula), and reach about 57 seconds on the tester's system for n=36, which is quite enough for the questioner's case.

Comment: There's also a way to solve this problem using a bipartite graph with pieces of lines in one side and pieces of columns in the other. And you create edges between these pieces if they can "attack" each other. Then, the answer to the problem is the maximum matching for this graph.